# Android ActionBar change Item color on click

Tags: android, colors, android-actionbar

In the action bar I have items that are presented in text, not icons. On click I want to change the color of this text from blue to white. I don't want to change the background with the

```
<item name="selectableItemBackground"></item>
```

only the text color. Anyone has any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo">
    <item name="android:actionMenuTextColor">@color/action_item_text_color</item>
</style>
```

`R.color.action_item_text_color`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:color="#fff"/>
    <item android:color="#00f"/>
</selector>
```

Comment: This doesn't work...it says that the tag requires android:color attribute

Comment: That's weird. Works for me, I tested it. I made little edits according to http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/color-list-resource.html. But ``android:color`` attribute was there before, as you can see it. If it still does not work, what SDK version are you using?

Comment: My Android SDK tools is revision 21.

Comment: ah OK, maybe I see the problem, I have put my selector in the drawable folder not in the color folder.

Comment: yeah that's it... and I wasted like 2-3 hours on this. Thanks!!

Comment: one more question, what attributes do I have to set so that the text stays white when i click on it?

Comment: I don't think this can be done with an action button. You would need to set a `ToggleButton` as a custom action view.